# N-to-N indexed relation in Java

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bidirectional multi-valued map in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066109/bidirectional-multi-valued-map-in-java)

I need a data structure that implements a N-to-N relation. Something like a `Map<Foo,Bar>` with calls:

```
getValues(Foo foo): Collection<Bar>
getValues(Bar bar): Collection<Foo>
```

and methods for the usual management like:

```
removeKey(Foo)   [remove all the <Foo,X> entries]
removeValue(Bar) [remove all the <X,Bar> entries]
```

Is there some library I can use or should I implement it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create 2 maps, each one from the key to collection of values:

`Map<Foo, Collection<Bar>>` and `Map<Bar, Collection<Foo>>`

If you wish you can create a class to wrap (Maybe use some generics for the types so you can easily reuse it) them inside and provide the methods you need

Comment: The alternative is of course to make a lookup function. Doing double bookkeeping is always a risk. If you must then make a class that wraps the two data structures, so you can test is properly.

Comment: From what I understood the relations are Bi-Directional, meaning x->y is not equivilang to y->x so there is no double bookkeeping.