# Which is the most efficient data structure for storing followers and follows

Tags: java, arrays

I have these two methods in java

- `public Int[] getFollows`
- `public Int[] getFollowers`

Where `getfollows(user1)` returns an array of `users` that  `user1` follows

and `getfollowers(user1)` returns an array of `users` that follow `user1`

My current data structure is an 2-d array so that I have

For every new follower of `user1` I run `followerArray[user1][followers++]=newFollower` 
This means that `getFollowers()`will run in O(1) time as I just `return followerArray[user1]`

However the method `getFollows()` will require me to use two `for` loops to search through all of the arrays N times so will run in O(N^2).

Is there a way that I can decrease the time complexity of the method `getFollows` without sacrificing the speed of `getFollowers()`

Comment: Well, if this 2D array is sufficient, use a second one that stores the inverse association.

Comment: List<UserEntity> -- JPA or DAO class for user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the data in whatever data structure you like. That's very coarsely what a database will do. The important step is its indices. In particular you have

```
AnyDataStructure users; // supports get(userKey) operation for some userKey; e.g. array index, integer, etc.
```

And you need to create two indices that you will maintain for look up.

```
Map<UserKey, List<UserKey>> followers = new HashMap<>();
Map<UserKey, List<UserKey>> follows = new HashMap<>();
```

yes, it's redundant. Indices are redundant. Note they're not *that* redundant though, in that they don't store the users duplicated again from scratch, just whatever key you use. You will have to maintain these with `AnyDataStructure`, i.e. any time a user is added, deleted, or a follower is added or deleted, you will have to maintain the maps too.

Note those maps perhaps should just be member variables of the `User` class.

```
List<UserKey> followers;
List<UserKey> following;
```

So that updating followers/following just updates the users themselves. This may not be maintainable as you add more and more features, but by this point you almost certainly should be doing this in a bona fide relational or NoSQL database anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066109/bidirectional-multi-valued-map-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You could use 2 Maps, one to keep track of followers and other for follows. It ensures constant look up time.

Answer (score 0):

using `HashSet` can reduce order to `O(n)` :

```
HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>  follows;

Integer[] getFollows(int user) {
    HashSet<Integer> r = follows.get(user);
    return r.toArray(new Integer[r.size()]);
}

Integer[] getFollowers(int user) {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer i : follows.keySet())
        if (follows.get(i).contains(user))
            a.add(i);
    return a.toArray(new Integer[a.size()]);
}
```