# How Can I search a Integer in a TreeMap<String, List<Integer>>?

Tags: java, treemap

I need to search if exist one Integer in the values of a `TreeMap<String, List<Integer>>`, how I can do it?

I need to search a particular integer value in all of the lists.

Comment: You'll have to explore up to every entry in the map.  You could consider doing so by iterating over its `values()` collection.

Comment: Do you want to know if there is a) exactly one integer value in total (i.e. all lists empty except one list which contains one integer) or b) a particular integer value in any of the lists or c) a particular integer value in all of the lists?

Comment: Use Guava MultiMaps and create your Bidirectional collection. Look at the example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39846050/7022735)

Comment: I need to search a particular integer value in all of the lists.